# Building the final web application

Tags: java, jsp

I have completed my Java web application and trying to deploy to the web host for hosting. But how do I 'compile everything'? I tried to build the project and landed with the following files.

> projectname.properties, projectbname.iml, projectname.xml,
>   module_projectname.xml

Do I just place them on the public hosted folder and its done? Or is there any guide. I keep coming across guides which assumes I know how to build. None seems to elaborate how to actually build and what files I need for hosting.

I am familiar with a website and where to place the html/css/js files. But this being a Java web app with all sorts of files, its confusing me. Please help.

Project Structure

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAQuN.jpg)

Comment: You really need to work on your googling skills...

Comment: @redFIVE Very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: While using google, check .jar and .war files

Comment: Those cannot be your only files. From the look of it, you seem to be using IDEA, fine; but you should consider using a dedicated build tool; and read a little more about what a "webapp" is in the Java world, how it is packaged, how your build tool can generate the necessary files for you, etc

Comment: Can you please update what framework of java you are using, what build system e.g Ant,Maven,Gradle being used? So that others can answer your question.

Comment: @fge Yes I am using Intellij. So I should get a dedicated build tool to do this? I got alot of files. But these were the ones created when I build.

Comment: @WitVault Its a very simple 4 page app. No framework was used. I just wrote the html/css/js files and used java to connect to database and perform some queries. I didn't use any of the build systems you mentioned (Don't think I used any at all).

Comment: @shammon share the screen-shot of your project structure. I guess you might be using servlets but can't be sure I have some more details.

Comment: @WitVault Added screenshot

Comment: I do not use IDEA, so this is only a comment. Whatever the build tool (ie maven, ant, gradle or maybe Intellij itself), it should end into a `.war` file. This is the file that must be deployed to the application server. Ok this is only the general guidelines, but it could be enough to understand what to research in IDEA and server documentations.

Comment: @SergeBallesta So to confirm, after writing a number of html,css,js,jsp,java,jar files - At the end I compile everything into 1 .war file and that is the only file needed. Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest use [**heroku**](https://www.heroku.com/) to deploy your web app. **Heroku** is very simple cloud based hosting quite useful for beginners and is easy to start with.

First read [**Getting Started with Java on Heroku**](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#introduction) carefully and then

follow the below instruction to deploy your app.

[Deploying from IntelliJ IDEA](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-to-heroku-from-eclipse-or-intellij-idea#deploying-from-intellij-idea)

Comment: Managed to build a war file and deploy on Heroku. Heroku was really easy to follow with no stumbles. Thank you.